# how to run php-scripts in coldfusion 8 - both inline and from htdocs folder?

Tags: php, apache, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Probably crossing a line here... I'm working on a system which runs Coldfusion8.

There are also some PHP Scripts running in the system and I'm having trouble setting this up on my localhost (newbie...)

I have **Apache 2.2** with **Coldfusion8** and **MySQL 5.5** working. **PHP 5.2** is installed,  but... dead...

Right now I'm tinkering with custom  tags from [here](http://scripting.riaforge.org/wiki/index.cfm/UsingPHPInColdFusion), which I managed to run inline (great helper file [here](http://scripting.riaforge.org/wiki/index.cfm/UsingPHPInColdFusion)) but this will only get me half way to the finish line = it only works on the page.

I'm looking for a way to run a php-file which sits in my Apache-htdocs-folder. I can call the script from .htaccess, but nothing really happens. Here is the call:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine On

   # Block
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !assets
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ai-cache

   # Redirect to PHP
   RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ script.php

</IfModule>
```

**Question:**
Can anyone tell me if that is possible and how I would go about it? A solution that would not force me to uninstall and reinstall everything would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want CF & PHP to coexist on a system?  or you want CF to invoke execute the PHP script??

Comment: Just run the script! No extra baggage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a php function within <script> tag from coldfusion 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085765/how-to-call-a-php-function-within-script-tag-from-coldfusion-9)

Comment: @Henry: I can run a PHP inline - that's the duplicate question you are refering to. I'm looking for a way to exec a standalone PHP file, which I'm triggering through .htaccess, when I'm running Coldfusion/Apache vs. PHP/Apache.

Comment: do you mean you want to invoke a PHP web service from CF?

Comment: I guess. I'm trying to setup an existing Coldfusion project on localhost. The project runs some PHP files (mostly for PDF generation), and as I have to modify parts of this, too, I'm trying to replicate the "Online Environment" on my localhost, where I also need the .php files to run.

Comment: So you just need instructions to set up Apache to serve both CF & PHP then, correct?  Google and you shall find the solution.

Comment: ;-) I will repost if Google & me don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a standard Lamp stack and make sure apache is running your PHP scripts. Then install CF correctly ... done.  Or, if CF is already installed, run the "connector" scripts (found in the /bin/connectors directory usually).

Comment: Ah I was looking for the CF is already installed... it was such a pain (first time) to connect CF, MySQL and the Webserver, that I really did not want to start over. Thanks! I'll give it a shot and get back to posting once I get somewhere. Thanks again!